# getchar and buffer, EOF

Tags: c, buffer, eof

```
/* getchar.c */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is an example code of `getchar()` and `putchar()` in 'a book on C'. Then I heard simply from my professor that how `getchar()` works.

1. standatd input is stored in buffer.
2. `getchar()` read a character from buffer at once.
3. if there is no more character, then buffer return -1.
4. There is `<` called 'redirection' which can be substitution(poor english...) of standard input.

`$ gcc getchar.c -o getchar`

`echo "abc" > input`

It worked when I use `<` redirection as an input.

`$ ./getchar < input`,

 But when I just typed, it didn't terminated.

 `$ ./getchar` 
 `abc`

Then I thought that maybe I misunderstood and this process will be correct:

1. when I use `<`, a contents input 'file' is stored in buffer with `EOF (= -1)` like a `NULL` of string.
2. So `getchar()` read `-1` when it read all contents of input file in buffer, and loop terminates.
3. when I just typed(standard input), then what I typed is stored in buffer with `'\n' (End Of Line)`.
4. So `getchar()` read `\n` when it read all contents of standard input in buffer, and loop doesn't terminate.

Is it correct? or is there anything that I don't know? (e.g. buffer really returns -1 but conditionally, ...)

Comment: When you don't use redirection, there's no automatic `EOF` that the program is looking for. On POSIX systems like Linux and macOS you must press the `Ctrl-D` key combination. On Windows it's `Ctrl-Z` (on a new line). When you use input redirection the `EOF` is sent to your program when the actual file ends.

Comment: https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/ is a good read.